# Regex validation code for excel file upload (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, excel

I want to validate excel files while uplaoding, I need to validate `.xlsx|.xlsm|.xls` files.

**[JS Bin link](http://jsbin.com/lifiyixezo/1/edit?html,js,output)**

anybody help me.

Comment: so whats the problem ?

Comment: its not working. If i add excel files too..

Comment: You want to validate only file extension, or the file name as well?

Comment: @dr_dev both file name(alphanumeric and special characters) and extension.

Comment: @Kasra, extension validation is enough for me now. could you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want validate only extension use this.

[demo](http://jsbin.com/hocuqayeti/1/edit?html,js,output)

```
jQuery("#upload").validate({
        expression: "if (VAL.match(/\.(xls[mx]?)$/) && VAL) return true; else return false;",
        message: "Please upload valid excel file"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
# Custom Method 

var file=$('#inpFile').val();

if (!(/\.(xlsx|xls|xlsm)$/i).test(file)) {
    alert('Please upload valid excel file .xlsx, .xlsm, .xls only.');
    $(file).val('');
}
else{
    alert('File uploded')// write your code here to upload file
}

#  Another Way to validate 

$('#upload').validate({
    rules: {
        resume: {
            required: true,
            extension: "xlsx|xls|xlsm"
        }
    },
    messages: {
        resume: {
            required: "file .xlsx, .xlsm, .xls only.",
            extension: "Please upload valid file formats .xlsx, .xlsm, .xls only."
        }
    }
});
```

I hope it will work for you.

Thanks.